# Shared Variable Used Globally in Angular 6 Components

Tags: observable, angular6

I am working on **Angular6** **todo list** task app.
I have tasks **categories** when **click** on category 
I get this **category's tasks** 
it working with me well but I need to set categories in **nav-component** like image below.
 so I need store **selected category** id in value to use it in **todo-component** 
any help ..?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to make a **shareable Object :**

create new service called **GlobaleVariable.ts** 
and write this on it :

```
@Injectable()
export class GlobalVariblesClass {    
 sharedCategory$ = new ReplaySubject<Groups>(1);

 updateCategoryValue(g: Groups) {

      return this.sharedCategory$.next(g);
   }
}
```

then you can **inject** this class in any **Component** **Constructor** to use it :)